# MySQL SOURCE Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue with the MySQL SOURCE command. I am getting the following error:

```
1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOURCE /var/www/apps/modx_install.sql' at line 1
```

The query I am executing is as follows:

```
mysql_query('SOURCE /var/www/apps/modx_install.sql;')
```

I was wondering what I was doing wrong here as I have read from several sources that this is the correct syntax.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also post the complete query, causing the error?

Comment: Please *always* show the full query that leads to the error. We aren't psychics; we can't know what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry chaps, it's a bit early for me! Post edited to include query.

Comment: Offtopic; early? It's 11:38 (am) here.. But then again, I'm from Holland ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it seems your MySQL-Server doesn't know the source command.

If you have shell access you could use

```
mysql --user=$user --password=$password $database < $file
```

You can try the same from within PHP

```
shell( "mysql --user=$user --password=$password $database < $file" );
```

Cheers.
haggi

Comment: +1 `SOURCE` is not a native mySQL command (just checked the docs), but one specific to the command line client.

Comment: I was getting the error in the MySQL command line too. For some reason, `source <filename>` did not work anymore. `source \. <filename>` made it work again. MySQL 5.6.20-win32

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try yet, but according to a comment at http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php, you should use LOAD DATA INFILE as an alternative of SOURCE.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SOURCE '/var/www/apps/modx_install.sql'")
```

Comment: That's my guess to, since ';' won't be in the actual filename.

Comment: Still no luck, getting the same error: Check syntax, etc.. 'SOURCE '/var/www/apps/autoinstall/modx_install.sql''

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (as I know `SOURCE` command is only implemented in the command line tool) and running shell command was not possible. I've found the following: if the sql command is `SOURCE` I cut the parameter (a filename) and try to process it. (I use my own mysql library, `db_Exec()` has the same effect as `mysql_query()`.)

```
    function db_Exec_plus($query) {
    $tmp = explode(" ", trim($query), 2);
    if(isset($tmp[0]) && strtoupper(trim($tmp[0]))=='SOURCE') {
        if (isset($tmp[1]) && file_exists($tmp[1])) {
            $result_array = array();
            $fp = fopen($tmp[1], "r");
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $cmd = trim(fgets($fp));
                $result_array[] = db_Exec($cmd);
            }
            fclose($fp);
            return $result_array;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return db_Exec($query);
    }
}
```